# Racket random list-ref function

Tags: scheme, racket

> Define a function that takes a non-empty list and returns an element of the list selected at random and with equal probability. (Do not use the built-in list-ref procedure.)

I'm stuck on this. I feel like you would need to count the number of times the function has run recursively and compare it to the random number you get, but I don't know how to do that in BSL+. Any help would be really great.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. To get the ball rolling the first element of the list is chosen as a candidate to be returned. Then for each element of the remaining elements in the list, we randomly choose if the candidate is to be replaced.

For example: For a list with two elements '(a b) first the element 'a is chosen.
The a coin is flipped: With probability 50% 'b is returned instead.

Examine the code to see how the algorithm works for larger lists:

```
(define (pick-random xs)
  (pick-random/helper (rest xs) (first xs) 1))

(define (pick-random/helper xs chosen k)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) chosen]
    [else  ; with probability 1/(k+1) choose the first element of xs
     (if (= (random (+ k 1)) 0)
         (pick-random/helper (rest xs) (first xs) (+ k 1))
         (pick-random/helper (rest xs) chosen     (+ k 1)))]))
```

If you want to google the theory, this type of algorithm belongs to "sampling algorithms".

Comment: This works, but I'm not sure why. Why did you choose (random (k+1)) as opposed to (+ 1 (random (length xs)))?

Comment: (length xs) takes time proportional to the length of the list. If you run through a list and keeps calling length (on the shorter and short list) your algorithm will take time O(n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1) = O(n^2). Using random on k+1 will be O(1).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I thought there was a way to take the length one time and set it as a default instead of running it everytime in the recursion.

Comment: If that were the only problem, you could use the solution of GoNZoo. Try simulating the algorithm with a list of three elements to see why 1/(k+1) works.

Answer (score 0):

I take the comment about not using list-ref as a direction to think about the problem recursively.

An assumption is made that 'equal probability' does not take into account the flaws of naive software-based RNGs.

Note that we use [[]-notation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-general-functions.html?q=optional#%28part._contracts-optional%29) in the function definition to say that steps, unless specified, will have a (default) value of **([random](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._random%29%29) (length lst))**. This means it will initially have a random amount of 'steps into' the list.

```
#lang racket

(define (random-element lst [steps (random (length lst))])
  (if (= steps 0)
      (first lst)
      (random-element (rest lst)
                      (sub1 steps))))
```

Since steps is internally specified (as **(sub1 steps)**, subtract one from steps) it will always have an explicit value except when the function is applied like so:

```
(random-element '(42 1337 128 256))
; 256
```

Comment: This is good, but [] notation doesn't run in BSL+. (random-element lst) only can have one variable lst, so I assume you would need a helper function set to the random probability, but in order for the program to work you need to *both* sub1 from the helper function and return (random-element (rest lst)) but Racket programming only allows you to return one thing, not two.

Comment: Actually, you can return several things with the help of [values](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29).